# How can I fix resolving domain names with wireguard?

Tags: dns, vpn, openvpn, wireguard

I've installed Wireguard and I successfully connect to my VPN network but I can't resolve domain names using DNS of the VPN network. I can ping internal nodes and I can get IP address that is bound to the domain by nslookup but ping, curl etc can't do this.

I use openvpn also so resolving of domain names works using openvpn connection works fine.

How can I fix resolving domain names with wireguard?

OS: Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: Could you post contents of /etc/resolv.conf when connected and when not.

Comment: VPN DOWN http://vpaste.net/8NMre
VPN UP http://vpaste.net/InbMa

Comment: please include also your ifconfig and route output. Is your vpn outpoint nameserver 192.168.241.1

Comment: It appears I fixed the issue changing configuration of Name Service Switch (NSS). The service is used by libc to have a deal with name services. So as far as I got my configuration of NSS make resolving stopped if a name is not resolved by Multicast DNS. Long story short I moved `dns` between `mdns4_minimal` and `[NOTFOUND=return]`. See http://vpaste.net/GYtsP. I'm not sure that it's a solution because I don't understand what happens if a name is not resolved by a DNS host. So I hope to see clarification of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `CONFIGURATION` section of `wg-quick` man page, worded in a not so obvious way:

```
   •      DNS — a comma-separated list of IP (v4 or v6) addresses to be set as the interface's DNS servers, or non-IP hostnames to be set as  the  in‐
          terface's  DNS  search domains. May be specified multiple times. Upon bringing the interface up, this runs `resolvconf -a tun.INTERFACE -m 0
          -x` and upon bringing it down, this runs `resolvconf -d tun.INTERFACE`. If these particular invocations of  resolvconf(8)  are  undesirable,
          the PostUp and PostDown keys below may be used instead.
```

Which states that you can include a `search` domain in the `[Interface]` section of your `/etc/wireguard/wg.conf` file, along with your DNS server entry:

```
[Interface]
DNS = 10.10.10.1, localdomain
```

Change the IP `10.10.10.1` to the DNS server IP in your remote `wg` network, update the `localdomain` to reflect the domain name used in the remote `wg` network.

eg. if you have a `[Peer]` section that contains, for example, RFC1918 addresses:

```
[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16
```

Then a query for `myserver` will be send to `10.10.10.1` as `myserver.localdomain`
(your remote DNS server will obviously needs to be able to resolve that host)

If you have multiple domains that can be resolved by the remote DNS server, then they can also be apended to the `DNS =` entry above, each entry separated by a comma.

All this is handled outside of your regular host `/etc/resolv.conf` and uses `resolvconf` behind the scenes to add additional DNS details that are added/removed dynamically upon a `wg` interface going up/down.

**Caveat:** I don't know (haven't tested) what presedence is used when sending queries, so you may be sending queries to multiple `wg` remote DNS servers, if you have more than one active, and thus you could be leaking host details to that remote DNS server that may be undesirable.

HTH