# Can not resolve domains in wireguard network on xubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, dns, vpn, wireguard

On my Xubuntu 20.04 desktop computer when connected to a wireguard network resolving domain names fails. It works just fine for other clients (Android phone and a Debian10 SBC). The VPN server resolves the names and the clients are configured to use it.

While connected to the wireguard network domain name resolution does not work for the browsers anymore (I tried multiple). In contrast `curl` and pinging domain names both work and `nslookup` is also able to find the IP addresses for any public domain name.

This issue has [been dealt with before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132981/how-can-i-fix-resolving-domain-names-with-wireguard), but the solution given in the comments does not work for me.

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my system was not up to date. A simple `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` fixed all the issues. It's the basics ...